# How to turn horizontal family tree to vertical?

Tags: html, css

There is horizontal family tree in this pen:
https://codepen.io/Muhsalp/pen/pBbNEX
How can I turn this family tree to vertical?
Box 1 will be at the top. Box 1.1 and box 1.2 will be under its.

```
<div id='wrapper'><span class='label'>1</span><div class='branch lv1'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1.1</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1.2</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.2</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>1.1.2.1</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.2</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>1.2.1</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write **CSS** for vertical chart. Just add `verticalChart` class in `wrapper` element.

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper' class="verticalChart">
```

**CSS**

```
.verticalChart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.verticalChart .label {
  position: static !important;
  margin: 0 10px !important;
}

.verticalChart .branch {
  margin: 100px 0 0 !important;
  display: flex;
}

.verticalChart .branch:before {
  border-left: 2px solid yellow;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  top: -101px !important;
}

.verticalChart .entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.verticalChart .entry:before {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 0 !important;
  top: -52px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:after {
    height: 49px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    border-left: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:after {
    width: 10px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:after {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 0;
    top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry.sole:after {
    height: 51px;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

I just update the mentioned changes in below code snippet. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
*, *:before, *:after{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin: 0px;}
#wrapper{position: relative;}
.branch{position: relative; margin-left: 250px;}
.branch:before {
content: "";
width: 50px;
border-top: 2px solid yellow;
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
position: relative;
min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
content: "";
height: 100%;
border-left: 2px solid red;
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
content: "";
width: 50px;
border-top: 2px solid blue;
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
width: 10px;
height: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 2px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
height: 10px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
width: 10px;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
height: 10px;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid green;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
width: 50px;
height: 0;
margin-top: 1px;
border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
display: block;
min-width: 150px;
padding: 5px 10px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid purple;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -15px;
}
.verticalChart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.verticalChart .label {
  position: static !important;
  margin: 0 10px !important;
}

.verticalChart .branch {
  margin: 100px 0 0 !important;
  display: flex;
}

.verticalChart .branch:before {
  border-left: 2px solid yellow;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  top: -101px !important;
}

.verticalChart .entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.verticalChart .entry:before {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 0 !important;
  top: -52px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:after {
    height: 49px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    border-left: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:after {
    width: 10px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:after {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 0;
    top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry.sole:after {
    height: 51px;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper' class="verticalChart">
  <span class='label'>1</span>
  <div class='branch lv1'>
      <div class='entry'>
          <span class='label'>1.1</span>
          <div class='branch lv2'>
              <div class='entry'>
                  <span class='label'>1.1.1</span>
                  <div class='branch lv3'>
                      <div class='entry'>
                          <span class='label'>1.1.1.1</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class='entry'>
                          <span class='label'>1.1.1.2</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class='entry'>
                  <span class='label'>1.1.2</span>
                  <div class='branch lv3'>
                      <div class='entry sole'>
                          <span class='label'>1.1.2.1</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='entry'>
          <span class='label'>1.2</span>
          <div class='branch lv2'>
              <div class='entry sole'>
                  <span class='label'>1.2.1</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen Metioned Changes resolved in a below code snippet. Thanks**

```css
*, *:before, *:after{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin: 0px;}
#wrapper{position: relative;}
.branch{position: relative;}
.branch:before {
content: "";
width: 50px;
border-top: 2px solid yellow;
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
position: relative;
min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
content: "";
height: 100%;
border-left: 2px solid red;
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
content: "";
width: 50px;
border-top: 2px solid blue;
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
width: 10px;
height: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 2px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
height: 10px;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
width: 10px;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
height: 10px;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid green;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
width: 50px;
height: 0;
margin-top: 1px;
border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
display: block;
min-width: 150px;
padding: 5px 10px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid purple;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -15px;
}
.verticalChart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.verticalChart .label {
  position: static !important;
  margin: 0 10px !important;
}

.verticalChart .branch {
  margin: 100px 0 0 !important;
  display: flex;
}

.verticalChart .branch:before {
  border-left: 2px solid yellow;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  top: -101px !important;
}

.verticalChart .entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.verticalChart .entry:before {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 0 !important;
  top: -50px;
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:last-child:after {
    height: 49px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    border-left: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.verticalChart .entry:first-child:after {
    width: 10px;
}

.verticalChart .entry:after {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 0;
    top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
}

.verticalChart .entry.sole:after {
    height: 51px;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper' class='verticalChart'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv1'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>XXX</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>XXX</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but there are small problems, can you fix them https://codepen.io/Muhsalp/pen/MRevpB Thank you

Comment: @MuhammetSönmezalp i just update your codepen  link with few CSS changes. Thanks

Comment: I just update your [codepen](https://codepen.io/Muhsalp/pen/MRevpB) and also add codepen code in the above answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the CSS `transform: rotate()` property.  I created a custom CSS class called `rotate` which I attached to your root `<div>` with an identifier of wrapper i.e. `<div id:"wrapper">`.

```
.rotate {
   transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

to perform a 90 degree rotation which aligned your graph vertically as opposed to horizontally.

I also added a `margin-top` property in the custom `rotate` class to move your graph down into view. Although you may have to fiddle around with this as you have hardcoded element sizes. Attached below is my code sandbox with the working example:

```css
*, *:before, *:after{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin: 0px;}
#wrapper{position: relative;}
.branch{position: relative; margin-left: 250px;}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.rotate {
   margin-top: 160px;
   transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper' class="rotate"><span class='label'>1</span><div class='branch lv1'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1.1</span></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.1.2</span></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.1.2</span><div class='branch lv3'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>1.1.2.1</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class='entry'><span class='label'>1.2</span><div class='branch lv2'><div class='entry sole'><span class='label'>1.2.1</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I don't want that way. Texts will remain unturned. Like this: https://prnt.sc/n83xjc.